# How to create a tab bar that imitates the look an feel of a GtkNotebook?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Im developing a GTK+ 3 application that should be able to display multiple files in tabs. But a GtkNotebook widget is not suitable for this, as it implies a functionality where every single page is a separate container. In the case of my application I just need some sort of tab bar to connect to application's logic, which will then change the data displayed by the ever same set of widgets.

How can this be achieved without ugly workarounds?

Comment: Maybe GtkButtonBox?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking of. I was just looking for a way to make it look like a tab bar in terms of display, tab-width and scrolling / floating.